# Multiple insert query using query builder in typeorm fails for oracle

Tags: node.js, oracle, typeorm

I am trying to insert multiple rows in oracle db using typeorm in nodejs. I am running below query:

```
const result = [
  { agent: 'linux', bytes: 12, responsible_request_id: '1234-4567-7890-0123' },
  { agent: 'windows', bytes: 200, responsible_request_id: '1234-4567-7890-0123' },
];

    await connection
        .createQueryBuilder(queryRunner)
        .insert()
        .into('STORAGE_AGENT.testcollection')
        .values(result)
        .exec()
```

I am getting this kind of logs in my terminal for this:

```
query: INSERT INTO "STORAGE_AGENT"."testcollection" (:1, :2, :3), (:4, :5, :6) -- PARAMETERS:        ["linux",12,"1234-4567-7890-0123","windows",200,"1234-4567-7890-0123"]
query failed: INSERT INTO "STORAGE_AGENT"."testcollection" (:1, :2, :3), (:4, :5, :6) --     PARAMETERS: ["linux",12,"1234-4567-7890-0123","windows",200,"1234-4567-7890-0123"]
error: Error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
[19/5/2023, 2:58:35 pm] ERROR : ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
QueryFailedError: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

It seems like this is some issue because of multiple insert which might be not supported in oracle. I am not very well versed in oracle so can you help me change my query builder to how let it insert multiple rows. I have to use query builder only, can't use pure queries as I am not only creating this for supporting oracle but many other DBs also.

Comment: Bulk insert is supported in Oracle but that syntax is not supported. You either want to use `INSERT ALL` or `INSERT ... SELECT ... UNION ALL SELECT ...`. Unfortunately, I don't know TypeORM to be able to tell you if it (a) supports the required syntax and (b) how to implement it.

Comment: @MT0 Thanks for your reply and letting me know two possible ways I can do it in raw query. Let's wait if someone can let us know how to handle it in typeorm also.